# How to make Caesar cipher case sensitive?

Tags: python

currently working on an assignment that requires me to write a script that inputs a line of encrypted text and a distance value and outputs plaintext using a Caesar cipher. I've done that and it works great for lower case letters however it does not work for capital letters or symbols (such as spaces or commas etc). What do I add to make the program work to the extent I need it to?

Thanks, here is my code

```
text = input("Enter the coded text: ")
dist = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))

plain = ""

for ch in text:
    ordvalue = ord(ch)
    cipher = ordvalue - dist
    if cipher < ord("a"):
        cipher = ord("z") - (dist - (ord("a") - ordvalue - 1))

    plain += chr(cipher)
print(plain)
```

Comment: Have you tried `ord('A')`, `ord('Z')`, `ord('.')`, etc. to see what they return?

Comment: You're so close to answer. You can type `man ascii` in shell to take a look at ASCII. You can figure out how to handle range A-Z

Comment: I've tried adding an elif to it with ord('A') and what not. But then if I type in "Lipps${svph%" which is supposed to return "Hello World" I get "ello²world±"

Comment: Also, typing "man ascii" into the shell just returns invalid syntax

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone I figured it out. the if statement in this was entirely unnecessary and could just be taken out which solved the problem.

Comment: Maybe also examine `maketrans`